# Not able to execute multiple queries in Spark structured streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have created a sample code to execute multiple queries. But I am getting output of only first query.
In the logs I am able to see that all the queries are running.Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
public class A extends D implements Serializable {

    public Dataset<Row> getDataSet(SparkSession session) {
        Dataset<Row> dfs = session.readStream().format("socket").option("host", hostname).option("port", port).load();
        publish(dfs.toDF(), "reader");
        return dfs;
    }

}

public class B extends D implements Serializable {

    public Dataset<Row> execute(Dataset<Row> ds) {
       Dataset<Row> d = ds.select(functions.explode(functions.split(ds.col("value"), "\\s+")));
        publish(d.toDF(), "component");
        return d;
    }
}

public class C extends D implements Serializable {

    public Dataset<Row> execute(Dataset<Row> ds) {

        publish(inputDataSet.toDF(), "console");
        ds.writeStream().format("csv").option("path", "hdfs://hostname:9000/user/abc/data1/")
                .option("checkpointLocation", "hdfs://hostname:9000/user/abc/cp").outputMode("append").start();
        return ds;
    }

}

public class D {

    public void publish(Dataset<Row> dataset, String directory) {
        dataset.writeStream().format("csv").option("path", "hdfs://hostname:9000/user/abc/" + directory)
                .option("checkpointLocation", "hdfs://hostname:9000/user/abc/checkpoint/" + directory).outputMode("append")
                .start();

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SparkSession session = createSession();
    try {
        A a = new A();
        Dataset<Row> records = a.getDataSet(session);

        B b = new B();
        Dataset<Row> ds = b.execute(records);

        C c = new C();
        c.execute(ds);
        session.streams().awaitAnyTermination();
    } catch (StreamingQueryException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the input socket that you are reading from.Spark socket source opens two connections to nc(ie since you have two start). Its a limitation of nc that it can feed data to one connection only.For other input sources ,your query should run fine.
See related question :
[Executing separate streaming queries in spark structured streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45618489/executing-separate-streaming-queries-in-spark-structured-streaming)

Tried  a simple test like below and prints both the output:

```
 val df1 = spark.readStream.format("socket").option("host","localhost").option("port",5430).load()

  val df9 = spark.readStream.format("socket").option("host","localhost").option("port",5431).load()


  val df2 = df1.as[String].flatMap(x=>x.split(","))

  val df3 = df9.as[String].flatMap(x=>x.split(",")).select($"value".as("name"))

 val sq1 = df3.writeStream.format("console").queryName("sq1")
    .option("truncate","false").trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(10 second)).start()

  val sq = df2.writeStream.format("console").queryName("sq")
    .option("truncate","false").trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(20 second)).start()

spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

Comment: I have same problem with kafka source with single partition